# Why is my variable only updating when a delay is put in a while(true) loop

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

This is a bit of a strange situation that I am unsure of the cause of the problem.

Here is the code (java):

```
while (true) {

        if (!pause) {

            // move enemies
            moveEnemies();

            // shoot towers
            shootTowers();

            // Move all bullets
            bulletFlight();

            // add a delay
            sleep();

        }



    }
```

The pause variable is the one which is not updating when changed from an external class, but it does change if I put some sort of process outside the while loop (for example moving sleep outside the if statement).

I know exactly how to fix my problem (as mentioned above) but I have no idea why the fix works. The problem is also fixed if I try to debug the code (putting a breakpoint at the if statement).

Can someone please enlighten me on the reason for my problem?

I don't mind posting more code (or the whole project) if needed.

Thanks

Comment: Is `pause` `volatile`? Does it help if you make it `volatile`?

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of what a volatile variable was (I'm in grade 12 CS) and it seems to have fixed it. I now understand why it wasn't updating. If you want the points for the answer feel free to add one and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: when pause is set to false, your loop is equivalent to while(true){}. So if you call this in the main thread your application will freeze and nothing more could happen in your app

Comment: @Colin I posted it as answer. If you don't want to delete your question feel free to mark it as solved by accepting answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you may have problem with caching value of `pause` by your threads. To prevent it make `pause` [`volatile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/do-you-ever-use-the-volatile-keyword-in-java).